# What do all the files do in androids 4.0 telephony database?

Tags: android, database, file, encryption, telephony

I'm just wondering what all the files do in android 4.0 telephony    databases directory?
I can read my messages from the mmssms.db-wal, even the deleted ones. In fact I cant even delete the db file it'll just show back up after reboot.
I do have root which is why its weird i can not delete it.

So my question is what do all the these files do:
("cdmatelephony.db", "cdmatelephony.db-journal", "mmssms.db", "mmssms.db-shm", "nwk-info.db", "telephony.db", "telephony.db-journal")

It doesn't really matter but I am curious of what the unreadable files are with the weird looking symbols! I assume they're either encrypted or maybe a program which has already been compiled and is unreadable like ("Machine Code") or something. 
Any help would be GREATLY  Appreciated so thank's in advance!!!

Comment: The `db` files are the regular database files. The other files are temp files used by SQLite. The `-journal` files are rollback journals, the `-wal` files are write-ahead logs, and the `-shm` files are share memory files. More information can be found [here](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html).

Comment: Ok that clears  it up a little bit.  I'll just have to read about that,  any clue why some of the files look like they're compiled? Also why the mmssms.db file comes back with all my txt messages after reboot i understand that the computer should recreate the file but why does it show back up with all the deleted data when i delete via ROOT!

Comment: "any clue why some of the files look like they're compiled?" - They're binary files. They aren't meant to be human-readable. "Also why the mmssms.db file comes back with all my txt messages after reboot" - Apparently a mirror copy is being kept somewhere. I couldn't say if that's a feature of Android itself, or of your particular vendor's version, but I'd imagine you could find out by slogging through the source code.

Comment: Right!!!! Kinda messed up for privacy. It comes from androidarea51 3rd party custom ROM's!!!!  I've had this phone for a few years now and have been via the whole directory ill see if i can't find what mirror it's at. thanks.  Do you think that someone could be backing up this file to a server or database  via port 80 without every being noticed?

Comment: O and i have to be prompted by super user before i can do anything root. I can't access the data files when not in root. So do you think the port 80 idea  is valid?

Comment: I guess it's a possibility, but just the fact that you're prompted for su isn't necessarily evidence of that.

Comment: No i set up my phone so i have to be prompted before anything root happens. But thank you for your insight i'm going to try and find the mirror file and learn how to completely erase any link. I run Nmap all the time  to scan my network and never seen another IP besides the devices that are on. Also i do service scans and there is no Services running on my ports in fact only 53 and 80 are open on my phone but I guess a service scan of  all more ports periodically throughout the day may figure out if my files are leaving my system. thank you again.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were saying. Anyhoo, no problem. Glad to help. Cheers!